# .htaccess get

Tags: .htaccess

есть http://siti/news/?PAGEN_1=1#nav_start как сделать 301 на http://siti/news/  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Якоря не пересылаются на сервер как часть запроса.**

**Вариант с помощью htaccess** (без якоря):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/news/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/? [R=301,L]
```

**Вариант на php** (без якоря):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/news/?PAGEN_1=1') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: /news/");
    exit();
}
```

Сделать редирект с помощью **.htaccess** или **php** с учетом якоря не выйдет.
Однако это можно сделать с помощью **javascript**.
Но и тут есть подвох: не выйдет переслать **301-й заголовок**, поскольку он формируется на сервере.

**Код на javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parse_url(str, component) {
        // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
        // + original by: Steven Levithan (http://blog.stevenlevithan.com)
        // + reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // + input by: Lorenzo Pisani
        // + input by: Tony
        // + improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // % note: Based on http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/assets/parseuri.js
        // % note: blog post at http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri
        // % note: demo at http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/assets/parseuri.js
        // % note: Does not replace invalid characters with '_' as in PHP, nor does it return false with
        // % note: a seriously malformed URL.
        // % note: Besides function name, is essentially the same as parseUri as well as our allowing
        // % note: an extra slash after the scheme/protocol (to allow file:/// as in PHP)
        // * example 1: parse_url('http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor');
        // * returns 1: {scheme: 'http', host: 'hostname', user: 'username', pass: 'password', path: '/path', query: 'arg=value', fragment: 'anchor'}
        var query, key = ['source', 'scheme', 'authority', 'userInfo', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port',
            'relative', 'path', 'directory', 'file', 'query', 'fragment'],
                ini = (this.php_js && this.php_js.ini) || {},
                mode = (ini['phpjs.parse_url.mode'] &&
                ini['phpjs.parse_url.mode'].local_value) || 'php',
                parser = {
            php: /^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/()(?:(?:()(?:([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?()(?:(()(?:(?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)()(?:[^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/,
            strict: /^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/,
            loose: /^(?:(?![^:@]+:[^:@\/]*@)([^:\/?#.]+):)?(?:\/\/\/?)?((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?)(((\/(?:[^?#](?![^?#\/]*\.[^?#\/.]+(?:[?#]|$)))*\/?)?([^?#\/]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/ // Added one optional slash to post-scheme to catch file:/// (should restrict this)
        };

        var m = parser[mode].exec(str),
                uri = {},
                i = 14;
        while (i--) {
            if (m[i]) {
                uri[key[i]] = m[i];
            }
        }

        if (component) {
            return uri[component.replace('PHP_URL_', '').toLowerCase()];
        }
        if (mode !== 'php') {
            var name = (ini['phpjs.parse_url.queryKey'] &&
                    ini['phpjs.parse_url.queryKey'].local_value) || 'queryKey';
            parser = /(?:^|&)([^&=]*)=?([^&]*)/g;
            uri[name] = {};
            query = uri[key[12]] || '';
            query.replace(parser, function($0, $1, $2) {
                if ($1) {
                    uri[name][$1] = $2;
                }
            });
        }
        delete uri.source;
        return uri;
    }
    url = parse_url(window.location);
    if (url.path === '/news/' && url.query === 'PAGEN_1=1' && url.fragment === 'nav_start') {
        window.location.replace('/news/');
    }
</script>
```

Если **301-й заголовок** нужен обязательно, то якорь придется опустить.
Если нужно что-то более сложное, то для работы с url есть прекрасная библиотека на javascript: **[URI](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)**

Answer (score 1):

Смоторя что имеется ввиду:

Вот либо так (если требуется именно это):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news/?PAGEN_1=1#nav_start [L,R=301]
```

Но я думаю, что под целью имеется ввиду именно вот это - статически через `mod_alias`

```
Redirect 301 /news/?PAGEN_1=1#nav_start http://siti/news/
```

Comment: не пашет, #nav_start  #=коммент (заменил на \%23)  тот же нулевой результат..

Comment: Не имею под рукой веб сервера, чтобы протестировать, но меня смущают 2 вещи:

1. Линк содержит якорь (анкор)
2. Оба `URL` ссылаются на то, что прописано в `DirectoryIndex` - т.е. на одну и ту же страницу.

Попробую попозже проверить.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Redirect 301
```

Но лучше резать урл в движке, зачем это в htaccess делать?

```
   $url = current(explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```